# Best way to model the dependency of these two random variables (copula?)

Tags: modeling, density-function, model, fitting, copula

I'm modelling the joint PDF of two variables that looks like this ,

[image: plot of alternative bivariate densities]

where vt and vr are the random variables. The dashed line shows the joint pdf assuming they are independent (the product of its marginals) and the solid line shows the measured joint PDF.

I have a model for the marginals, and therefore finding their copula might be the way to go. However I have no idea of what that cupola should be, since it doesn't seem to be Gaussian. Does anyone know what a good choice for a cupola could be?

Another option would be to directly fit the bi-variate distribution with a known PDF. For the marginals I use the Pearson type IV distribution. Any idea on bi-variate distributions that might work?

Comment: ?Transform to *copula data*, estimate parameters in some parametric copula models, and choose by AIC? Or some visualization, have a look at https://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/166842/A_1212.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: http://www.copulatheque.org might guide you visually, but before, I'd suggest to 'remove' the margins either by applying the CDFs or the rank-order transformation to obtain data on the copula scale [0,1]². Some people prefer N(0,1) marigns instead of the uniform ones. Calculating  Kendall's tau (or Spearman's rho) might also provide guidance on the copula choice - some families have a limited 'range'.

Comment: Did some of this links help? If not, and you still want some help, you can post (a link to) your data. Include it in your original question, use the *edit* button below the post.